# How to see the git commands VSCode do behind the scenes when I press "Sync Changes", "Commit", or "Add",...etc. buttons?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn Git, and the buttons make using Git very easy but I want to see the commands that take place behind the scenes.

Comment: I think if you go to the Output view and choose Git from the dropdown box, you will see all the individual Git commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Git output window.

You can always peek under the hood to see the Git commands.

To open the Git output window, run **View >> Output** and select **Log (Git)** from the dropdown list.